# One Primary Key for Multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

I'm new to SQL so I'm likely asking a question with a very obvious answer. I'm making a simple database for phone plans, my tables, in order, are:

COUNTRY, PROVIDER, PHONE, PLAN, CUSTOMER.

They all have one primary key, and except for COUNTRY all have foreign keys referencing to the previous table.

My issue arises when inserting values into the PHONE table. These are the PROVIDER and PHONE tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Provider_T(
    Name                VARCHAR(25),
    Provider_ID         CHAR(10)    NOT NULL,
    Country_Abbrev      CHAR(3)     DEFAULT NULL,
    Website             VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    CService_Number     VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Provider_T_PK PRIMARY KEY(Provider_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Country_Abbrev_FK FOREIGN KEY(Country_Abbrev) REFERENCES Country_T(Abbreviation));

CREATE TABLE Phone_T(
    Phone_Model         VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Provider_ID         CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
    Smartphone          BOOLEAN,
    CONSTRAINT Phone_Model_PK PRIMARY KEY(Phone_Model),
    CONSTRAINT Provider_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY(Provider_ID) REFERENCES Provider_T(Provider_ID));
```

This is my insert for the PHONE table:

```
INSERT INTO Phone_T(Phone_Model, Provider_ID, Smartphone) VALUES ("Nexus 5", "ROG", TRUE);
INSERT INTO Phone_T(Phone_Model, Provider_ID, Smartphone) VALUES ("Nexus 5", "KOD", TRUE);
```

I know I have duplicate Primary Keys, I'm stumped on how I could make one Phone Model for multiple PROVIDERS. I would love some advice and any help is appreciated.

Comment: If phone models exist independently to providers, then it makes no sense for the `Phone` table to have an FK into the `Provider` table; rather you would create an association table `PhoneProviders` to implement a many-to-many relationship—e.g. it would contain FKs into both the `Phone` and `Provider` tables and enable a single phone model to be associated with multiple providers (and also a single provider to be associated with multiple phone models).

Comment: In addition to what @eggyal mentioned, you should consider use of autoincrement primary keys.

Comment: @eggyal that makes sense, so the association table would link Phone and Providers to a Phone Model allowing me to have multiple models for multiple providers.